# Need help in pie-chart in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I am new to jquery and javascript. I am making a pie-chart and I want to highlight the pieces of pie-chart. I have succeeded in making a pie-chart but the problem with me is me on highlighting.

I have to highlight every piece of pie when mouse is over it. Now, when I search it on google then there are various plug-in avalible but is there a way to do without it. I tried by creating a jquery function and then when mouseover it should change highlight but I cannot do it by that way.

Here is my code---

```
<html> 
<body> 
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas"></canvas> 
<script> 
//initialize data set 
var data = [ 100, 68, 20, 30, 100 ];  
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
//draw background 
c.fillStyle = "white"; 
c.fillRect(0,0,500,500);  


//a list of colors 
var colors = [ "orange", "green", "blue", "yellow", "teal"];  
//calculate total of all data 
var total = 0; 
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
{     
total += data[i]; 
} 

//draw pie data 
var prevAngle = 0; 
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
{     //fraction that this pieslice represents     
var fraction = data[i]/total;     
//calc starting angle     
var angle = prevAngle + fraction*Math.PI*2;          
//draw the pie slice     
c.fillStyle = colors[i];          
//create a path     
c.beginPath();     
c.moveTo(250,250);     
c.arc(250,250, 100,prevAngle, angle, false);     
c.lineTo(250,250);          
//fill it     
c.fill();          
//stroke it     
c.strokeStyle = "black";     
c.stroke();          
//update for next time through the loop     
prevAngle = angle; } 



</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Pie chart should be highlighted something like below:**
[image]

Please help me with this. I know it simple but I am not able to figure out. Any help is appreciated. Please comment if you have any question?

Comment: you want the value of the pie share to be shown on hovering over it ?

Comment: I have edited the question. Added a image I want something like this.

Comment: you need to set   "sliced: true, selected: true" for the series you need    check this link http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/

Comment: @Raki here they have sliced:true to appear it different from others but I want when the cursor is there then it should be highlighted. But I don't want that I want when cursor is there it should be highlighted.

Comment: Check this updated fiddle with setTranslation function on hover http://jsfiddle.net/63eh9aty/1/

Comment: @Raki I checked it and it is very good but we have to give the proportion and in my case you have to give values and it will calculate automatically also function uses the argument but how do I give argument here

Comment: you should pass the values using JSON

Comment: @RRR Sorry I don't know how to do that

Comment: Kindly check the following... http://jsfiddle.net/oj4ychhr/2/   here we are taking the values from an external JSON

Comment: @RRR can you please tell me how do I create my own JSON file?

Comment: JSON is basically a Fat-Free Alternative to XML...  I recommend you to go through http://www.w3schools.com/json/ if you are uncomfortable using JSON you can go for arrays too for this particular chart

Comment: @RRR I visited that page but when and created the file but when I tried to use my own file but data didn't show up.

Comment: can you share your json file plz

Comment: @RRR it is your file only just I copied and placed it in the local folder with .json extension is there any format for that? I just copied and paste it there

Comment: replace the line`$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/51clc', function(data) {` with `$.getJSON("http://localhost:8888/test.json", function(data){`

Comment: replace 8888 with the port number which your server is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shubham Vashishtha: check this fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/63eh9aty/2/
Here I have created a `Json` variable **options** which has required setting for highcharts, then next step is to add data to the series. which is implemented by creating a `Json` variable called **"seriesOptions** which contains **name, data: [ ]** (which is array). In order to insert actual data into **data:[ ]** i have created **dataOptions** variable.
Next assigning data to **dataOptions** and adding each **dataOptions** to the **seriesOptions** finally adding seriesOptions data to the actual `series` of highchart .i.e **options.series.push(seriesOptions)** as shown in the fiddle.

Comment: that is very good...thank you so much for your effort...can you please just tell me how do I know which keyword is used for which property. Like if want any other functionality so where can I check?

Comment: you can refer this http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts, if my answers were helpful kindly vote.

Comment: yeah, it was very helpful...thank you again...One more thing can you please tell me how to remove that top-right icon that is used for print chart icon etc..I visited the  [api.highcharts.com/highcharts] page but couldn't find it

Comment: well it is called exporting option. which can be enabled or disabled by adding    exporting: { enabled: false }  for more details refer   http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha I hope your problem is solved.... Happy something worked out for you :)